# How to do group by in postgresql with multiple joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to group by dest_spot_id but couldn't able to get the desired result.

```
SELECT
    ddsd.dest_spot_id
  , ddsd.status
  , ddsd.data_type
  , ddsd.destination_id
  , ddsd.created_on
  , ddsd.data_id
  , gi.tp_destination_name  AS dest_or_spot_name
  , mt.taluk_name
  , md.district_name
  , tgi.tp_destination_name AS destination_name
FROM      dm_dest_spot_data ddsd 
LEFT JOIN m_district        md   ON md.id_district = ddsd.district_id
LEFT JOIN m_taluk           mt   ON mt.id_taluk = ddsd.taluk
JOIN      tp_general_info   gi   ON gi.id_tp_general_info = ddsd.dest_spot_id
LEFT JOIN tp_general_info   tgi  ON tgi.id_tp_general_info = ddsd.destination_id
GROUP BY
    1
  , 2
  , 3
  , 4
  , 5
  , 6
  , 7
  , 8
  , 9
  , 10
ORDER BY
  ddsd.data_id
```

dest_spot_id have common_ids but i want get one from it.
lets say this is my table

### dest_spot_id | status| so on

```
302      | 1      | 5
303      | 2      | 3
302      | 1      | 2
303      | 2      | 1
401      | 1      | 3
308      | 2      | 2
```

i want the outputs as :

### dest_spot_id | status| so on

```
302      | 1      | 5
303      | 2      | 3
401      | 1      | 3
308      | 2      | 2
```

please give my some advice to achieve this. i am new to postgresql

Comment: My advice is that you fix your formatting so others may actually read your query.  I have started editing to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you want to do with the other columns, but let's say you want the maximum value of everything except the dest_spot_id:

```
SELECT
    dest_spot_id
  , MAX(other_colum1)
  , MAX(other_colum2)
  , …
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  dest_spot_id
```

So you only group by the column(s) that should be unique in the output.

For the other columns you can apply some aggregation function like MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, etc.

It does not matter whether there are multiple table with JOINS or just one table.

The one thing that is different with multiple tables is that you have to qualify the column in the GROUP BY clause or use the fields position.

```
SELECT
    t1.dest_spot_id
  , MAX(t2.other_colum)
  , MAX(t3.other_colum)
  , …
FROM my_table1 t1
JOIN my_table2 t2 ON …
JOIN my_table3 t3 ON …
GROUP BY
  t1.dest_spot_id
```

or

```
SELECT
    t1.dest_spot_id
  , MAX(t2.other_colum)
  , MAX(t3.other_colum)
  , …
FROM my_table1 t1
JOIN my_table2 t2 ON …
JOIN my_table3 t3 ON …
GROUP BY
  1
```

Comment: Thank you jens it worked like charm.. meanwhile what is that max doing here.

Comment: When you have multiple different values for the same dest_spot_id, you have to somehow choose which one to use. MAX always takes the greatest value. MIN would take the least value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is my updated code after jens explanation. may it help someone..

```
SELECT 
    ddsd.dest_spot_id
    ,max(ddsd.status) as dest_spot_status
    ,max(gi.tp_destination_name)as dest_or_spot_name
    ,max(ddsd.created_on) as createdon
    ,max(mt.taluk_name) as taluk_name
    ,max(md.district_name) as district_name
    ,max(ddsd.data_type) as dataType
    ,max(ddsd.destination_id) as destination_idd
    ,max(tgi.tp_destination_name) as destination_name
    ,max(ddsd.data_id) as dataid
FROM dm_dest_spot_data ddsd
LEFT JOIN m_district md ON md.id_district = ddsd.district_id
LEFT JOIN m_taluk mt ON mt.id_taluk = ddsd.taluk
JOIN tp_general_info gi ON gi.id_tp_general_info = ddsd.dest_spot_id
LEFT JOIN tp_general_info as tgi ON tgi.id_tp_general_info = ddsd.destination_id
GROUP BY ddsd.dest_spot_id
ORDER BY max(ddsd.data_id) DESC
```